# Question on $\liminf A_{n}$ and $\limsup A_{n}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, supremum-and-infimum, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Say I have the following event $\{\limsup_{n \to \infty} |X_{n}|> \epsilon\}$, and that $P(\{\limsup_{n \to \infty} |X_{n}|> \epsilon\})$, I also realize that

$\{\limsup_{n \to \infty} |X_{n}|> \epsilon\}^{C}=\{\liminf_{n \to \infty} |X_{n}|\leq\epsilon\}$ and subsequently $P(\{\liminf_{n \to \infty} |X_{n}|\leq\epsilon\})=1$

Is my understanding of the statement "$P(\{\liminf_{n \to \infty} |X_{n}|\leq\epsilon\})=1$" correct in that:

$P(\{\liminf_{n \to \infty} |X_{n}|\leq\epsilon\})=1\iff\exists N \in \mathbb N, \forall n \geq N, |X_{n}|\leq\epsilon$ $P-$almost surely.

Am I confusing two separate notations here or are they equivalent?

Comment: Btw, there's also the tag "supremum and infinitum".

Comment: Same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3111478/does-p-liminf-n-to-infty-x-n-leq-epsilon-1-iff-exists-n-in-mat/3112035#3112035