# Does $P(\liminf_{n \to \infty}\{|X_{n}|\leq \epsilon\})=1\iff \exists N \in \mathbb N, |X_{n}|\leq \epsilon, \forall n \geq N, P-$a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, supremum-and-infimum, almost-everywhere, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Background to my question:

Given that $(X_{n})_{n}$ are random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and for $\epsilon > 0$: $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N}P(|X_{n}|>\epsilon)<\infty$

It follows from BCL that $P(\limsup_{n \to \infty}|X_{n}|>\epsilon)=0$ and therefore $P(\liminf_{n \to \infty}|X_{n}|\leq \epsilon)=1$

As the title suggests, is the definition of $P(\liminf_{n \to \infty}|X_{n}|\leq \epsilon)=1$ simply equivalent to:

$\exists N \in \mathbb N: |X_{n}|\leq\epsilon, \forall n \geq N, P-$a.s. or are there differences between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition,
\begin{align*}
 \omega \in \liminf A_n &\Longleftrightarrow \exists m_0 \in \mathbb N : \omega \in \bigcap_{n\geq m_0} A_n\\
 &\Longleftrightarrow \exists m_0 \in \mathbb N \, \forall n\geq m_0 : \omega \in A_n \\[.5em]
    &\Longleftrightarrow \omega \in A_n \text{ taken from (countably) infinitely many $n \in \mathbb N$ }\\
 &\Longleftrightarrow \omega \in A_n \text{ for all except finitely many $n \in \mathbb N$ (i.e., for cofinitely many $n$) } \\
    &\Longleftrightarrow \omega \text{ in ultimately all of $A_n$ $(n \in \mathbb N)$ } \\
    &\Longleftrightarrow A_n \text{ ultimately (ult.) } \\[.5em]
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
 \omega \in \limsup A_n &\Longleftrightarrow \forall m \in \mathbb N : \omega \in \bigcup_{n\geq m} A_n \\
 &\Longleftrightarrow \forall m \in \mathbb N \, \exists n_0(m)\geq m : \omega \in A_{n_0(m)} \\[.5em]
 &\Longleftrightarrow \omega \text{ appears in infinitely many of the $A_n$ }\\
 &\Longleftrightarrow \omega \in A_n \text{ for all but finitely many $n \in \mathbb N$ (i.e., cofinitely many $n$) } \\
    &\Longleftrightarrow A_n \text{ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb N$ } \\
    &\Longleftrightarrow A_n \text{ infinitely often  (i.o.)}. \\[.5em]
\end{align*}
So if $\mathbb P(\limsup A_n) = 0$, then the probability that infinitely many of $A_n$ occur is 0.

Comment: This does not answer my question

Comment: I just wrote the counterpart of your event.

What is the event in your case? It is $A_n(\epsilon) := \{X_n \leq \epsilon\}$.

When does an event $B$ occur with probability $1$ or, for short, $\mathbb P$-a.s.? If $\mathbb P(B) = 1$. 

Hence, if you combine line 2 of my answer with your data, what do you get?

Comment: I ascertain whether you're stating that my formulations are equivalent or not, $P(\liminf_{n \to \infty}|X_{n}|\leq \epsilon)=1 \iff \exists N \in \mathbb N: |X_{n}|\leq\epsilon, \forall n \geq N, P-$a.s.

Comment: You get exactly this, right!